# Display a value from a preceding-sibling of a following sibling/child node?

Tags: xslt, xpath

Based on this XML I am trying to display a table with a row for each DOCREF that also shows the STEP2/TITLE where the REFERENCE equals the ID.  I can make this work where the DOCREF/@REFERENCE = STEP2/@ID but where I am running into troubles is that it has been requested that the STEP2/TITLE also show for each STEP3 element until there is a new STEP2 element, and then it would show for all the STEP3's until it changes again and so on.

```
<WORKCARD>
  <STSBODY>
    <DOCREFS>
      <DOCREF REFERENCE="123" VALUE="Ref1"/>        
      <DOCREF REFERENCE="456" VALUE="Ref2"/>
      <DOCREF REFERENCE="789" VALUE="Ref3"/>
    </DOCREFS>
  </STSBODY>
  <BODY>
    <ITEMS>
      <ITEM>
        <XML>
          <STEP2 ID="123">
            <TITLE>Test1</TITLE>
          </STEP2>
        </XML>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM>
        <ITEMXML>
          <XML>
            <STEP3 ID=456>Step info goes here</STEP3>
          </XML>
        </ITEMXML>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM>
        <ITEMXML>
          <XML>
            <STEP2 ID=789>Test2</STEP3>
          </XML>
        </ITEMXML>
      </ITEM>
    </ITEMS>
  </BODY>
</WORKCARD>
```

I am modifying an existing XSLT.  Here is the section I am working with and you can see my various attempts that don't get me what I need.

```
<xsl:key name="step2Ref" match="STEP2" use="@ID" />

<xsl:when test="DOCREF[@TASK_CARD_ITEM > $item]">
  <xsl:for-each select="DOCREF[@TASK_CARD_ITEM > $item and not($doctype = 'NDT' and key('refItem', @TASK_CARD_ITEM)/descendant::L1ITEM[@ID] and not(key('refItem',@TASK_CARD_ITEM)/descendant::L2ITEM))]">
    <xsl:sort select="@TASK_CARD_ITEM" data-type="number" />
    <!--<xsl:call-template name="subtaskitemrow"/>-->

    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="6" border="solid 1pt red">
        <fo:block>
          <!-- this displays the correct info when there is a matching STEP2/@ID-->              
          <xsl:value-of select="key('step2Ref', @REFERENCE)/TITLE" />***                  
          <!--This gets the STEP2/TITLE where STEP2/@ID = @REFERENCE-->
          <xsl:value-of select="//STEP2/@ID" />+++
          <xsl:value-of select="//ITEM/@TASK_CARD_ITEM" />***
          <xsl:value-of select="@TASK_CARD_ITEM"/>+++
          <xsl:variable name="tcitem"><xsl:value-of select="@TASK_CARD_ITEM" /></xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="//ITEM[$tcitem]/@TASK_CARD_ITEM" />***
          <!--preceding-sibling STEP2/@ID-->
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>        
  </xsl:for-each>    
</xsl:when>
```

Some notes I've written to myself are:

- When looping through the DOCREFS I need to display the STEP2/TITLE for each one until the STEP2/TITLE changes and then display the new one.
- I need to match STEP3's preceding-sibling STEP2's @ID

Please help?

ETA:

Desired output for this sample (changed text in xml slightly from original post) would be something like this:

1. Test1
2. Test1
3. Test2

So for the first and second DOCREFs it would show the title from the first STEP2 and the third DOCREF would show the title from the second STEP2.

Comment: Could you include some desired output? Also: The `select` statements in the `<fo:block>` with prefixes `//` look a little suspiscious since they basically scan the _whole_ document irrespective of the context. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi and thank you for responding!  The // were my desperate attempts as I was getting rather frustrated :(

I'll add desired output to the original question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML document is not well-formed, and - more importantly - the second `<STEP2>` has no `<TITLE>`. Assuming it can be corrected to:

```
<WORKCARD>
  <STSBODY>
    <DOCREFS>
      <DOCREF REFERENCE="123" VALUE="Ref1"/>        
      <DOCREF REFERENCE="456" VALUE="Ref2"/>
      <DOCREF REFERENCE="789" VALUE="Ref3"/>
    </DOCREFS>
  </STSBODY>
  <BODY>
    <ITEMS>
      <ITEM>
        <XML>
          <STEP2 ID="123">
            <TITLE>Test1</TITLE>
          </STEP2>
        </XML>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM>
        <ITEMXML>
          <XML>
            <STEP3 ID="456">Step info goes here</STEP3>
          </XML>
        </ITEMXML>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM>
        <ITEMXML>
          <XML>
            <STEP2 ID="789">
                <TITLE>Test2</TITLE>
            </STEP2>
          </XML>
        </ITEMXML>
      </ITEM>
    </ITEMS>
  </BODY>
</WORKCARD>
```

you can use the following logic to retrieve the data you need (for testing purposes, more is shown than required in your question):

```
<xsl:key name="step2Ref" match="STEP2" use="@ID" />
...
<xsl:template match="DOCREF">
<tr>
    <!-- DOCREF VALUE-->
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@VALUE" /></td>
    <!-- DOCREF REFERENCE -->
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@REFERENCE" /></td>

    <xsl:variable name="ref">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="key('step2Ref', @REFERENCE)">
                <xsl:value-of select="@REFERENCE" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::DOCREF[key('step2Ref', @REFERENCE)][1]/@REFERENCE" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- REFERENCE USED FOR KEY -->
    <td><xsl:value-of select="$ref" /></td>
    <!-- RETRIEVED TITLE -->
    <td><xsl:value-of select="key('step2Ref', $ref)/TITLE" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>
```

In the above example, the following result is returned:

```
Ref1    123 123 Test1
Ref2    456 123 Test1
Ref3    789 789 Test2
```

Note that it is assumed that the first `<DOCREF>` *does* have a related `<STEP2>`.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much.  Now to figure one more piece of this out which what you've offered should help with :)